# How to open collapse if input has value?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make that, Show div if there is value in any input of div. I am using bootstap collapse.

I wrote a function like this but it didn't work

```
$(function() {
  $("collapseExample .collapse").each(function () {
if ($(this).find('.kgad2').length > 0)
  $(this).collapse('show');
});
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

here is html

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
<div class="card card-body">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table id="ekkagit" class="table table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th bgcolor="#00FF00">
                        <strong>Ek Kağıt 1</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>Tabaka</th>
                    <th>Kg Fiyatı</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="kgad2" name="kgad2" type="text" value="">
                            <?php echo $sonuc['kgad2'] ?>" class="form-control inst_amount7">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="kgfiyat2" name="kgfiyat2" type="text" value="">
                                <?php echo $sonuc['kgfiyat2'] ?>" class="form-control inst_amount7">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: by this `$(this).find('.kgad2').length` you are only finding the input length and not is value.

Comment: @KulshreshthK not input length, but how many .kgad2 was found (BTW there is no .kgad2 in the code and the mixture of php and html doesn't make sense)

Comment: yes @PavelTřupek, the provided code has lots of error, which is disturbing the dom.
like this  `<input id="kgad2" name="kgad2" type="text" value="">
                            <?php echo $sonuc['kgad2'] ?>" class="form-control inst_amount7">`
input tag is closed and the class is out of any tag.

Comment: PS: You're missing a hash in `$("collapseExample .collapse").each(function ()`. This should be `$("#collapseExample.collapse").each(function ()` But would you provide the same ID to many DIVs?